# passing object through directive scope not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, data-binding, angularjs-directive

I am trying to pass an object from a controller via my HTML template to a directive to use the object in another HTML template.

I got an controller with:

```
function controller($state, $rootScope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.residents = [object];
}
```

In my config:

```
function config($sateprovider) {
    [..],
    templateUrl: [..]/template.html,
    [..]
}
```

In the templtate.html I got:

```
<div ng-repeat="resident in controller.residents>
    <user-block user={{ resident }}></user-block>
</div>
```

In my user block directice I got:

```
function userBlock() {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: [..]/userblock.html,
    controller: 'blockController',
    controllerAs: 'blockCtrl',
    bindTocController: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        user: '@',
    }
}
```

And finaly in userblock.html:

```
<div>{{ blockCtrl.user }}</div>
```

I got the following output:

{"username":"Xiduzo","user_id":123,"experience":123456789,"total_energy":100,"energy_left":50,"rupees":[{"name":"emerald","amount":106},{"name":"sapphire","amount":43},{"name":"amethyst","amount":131},{"name":"ruby","amount":11},{"name":"citrine","amount":159},{"name":"coal","amount":23}]}

But when I want to get the username and do like:

```
<div>{{  blockCtrl.user.username }}</div>
```

I got no output at all.

Is there something I am missing or doing completely wrong?

Comment: Did you really leave out the quotes in `user={{ resident }}`?  Because that's definitely not going to work.  Try `user="{{ resident }}"`

Comment: Works fine without quotes, adding them doesn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the issue is you are using `@` binding(one way binding) by which you are passing `user` object to directive isolated scope. But the thing is @ coverts any type of varible in a string. So when user varible arrives to the directive `scope` it is not pure user `object`. Its nothing but stringified version of user JSON object.

That's why when you are trying to access it like JSON didn't worked.

I'd recommend you to pass that field using `=` (two way binding) will make it working and persist type of object.

Change

```
scope: {
    user: '@',
}
```

To

```
scope: {
    user: '=',
}
```

And

```
<user-block user=resident></user-block>
```

Comment: Should have mentioned that but inside my userBlock I got the controller and controllerAs. That's why {{ blockController.user }} is displaying data in the first place i guess?

Comment: @Xiduzo I don't see controller as in your directive, isn't you missed that?

Comment: My bad, updated the post. Thought this was irrelevant.

Comment: NICE, this solves the problem. Thank you so much. I'd also had to change user={{ resident }}' to user="resident" as Dave suggested